# Remove duplicate in a string - javascript

Tags: javascript

I have a string in javascript where there are a lot of duplicates. For example I have:

```
var x = "Int32,Int32,Int32,Int32,Int32,Int32,Int32,Int32,Int32,Double,Double,Double"
```

What can I do to delete duplicates and to get for example `x="Int32,Double"`?

Comment: Have you tried *anything*?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get all unique values in a JavaScript array (remove duplicates)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1960473/get-all-unique-values-in-a-javascript-array-remove-duplicates)

Answer (score 58, accepted):

With `Set` and `Array.from` this is pretty easy:

```
Array.from(new Set(x.split(','))).toString()
```

```js
var x = "Int32,Int32,Int32,Int32,Int32,Int32,Int32,Int32,Int32,Double,Double,Double"
x = Array.from(new Set(x.split(','))).toString();
document.write(x);
```

Comment: well done :) ^_^ but can u provide sample please on jsfiddle ?

Comment: @Microsmsm why...you can run this right in your console. And why can't you make a fiddle for it?

Comment: @Microsmsm there you go.

Comment: @Microsmsm - and note that you have to be using the latest Chrome or Firefox for that to work

Comment: And, it could be shortened with `x = [...new Set(x.split(','))].join(',');`

Answer (score 5):

Its simple just remove duplicates in string using `new Set` and `join` them.

```js
var x = "Int32,Int32,Int32,Int32,Int32,Int32,Int32,Int32,Int32,Double,Double,Double";
console.log([...new Set(x)].join(""));
```

Comment: `new Set` splitting by a comma... Javascript doesn't stop surprising in ages.

Answer (score 4):

If you have to support current browsers, you can split the array and then filter it

```js
var x = "Int32,Int32,Int32,Int32,Int32,Int32,Int32,Int32,Int32,Double,Double,Double";
    
var arr = x.split(',');
    
x = arr.filter(function(value, index, self) { 
    return self.indexOf(value) === index;
}).join(',');

document.body.innerHTML = x;
```

Answer (score 3):

Use new js syntax remove Dupicate from a string.

```
String.prototype.removeDuplicate = Function() {
  const set = new Set(this.split(','))
  return [...set].join(',')
}
x.removeDuplicate()
```

Answer (score 3):

```
  function myFunction(str) {
    var result = "";
    var freq = {};
    for(i=0;i<str.length;i++){
       let char = str[i];
       if(freq[char]) {
        freq[char]++;      
       } else {
        freq[char] =1
        result = result+char;
       }
    }
    return result;
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

That is a more readable and better parameterized solution:

```
var x = "Int32,Int32,Int32,Int32,Int32,Int32,Int32,Int32,Int32,Double,Double,Double"
var removeDup = [...new Set(x.split(","))].join(",");
```

//result "Int32,Double"

Answer (score 0):

```
function removeDuplicate(x)
{
    var a = x.split(',');
    var x2 = [];
    for (var i in a)
        if(x2.indexOf(a[i]) == -1) x2.push(a[i])
    return  x2.join(',');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function removeDups(s) {
let charArray = s.split("");
  for (let i = 0; i < charArray.length; i++) {
    for (let j = i + 1; j < charArray.length; j++)
      if (charArray[i] == charArray[j]) {
        charArray.splice(j, 1);
        j--;
      }
  }
  return charArray.join("");
}
console.log(removeDups("Int32,Int32,Int32,InInt32,Int32,Double,Double,Double"));
```

Answer (score 0):

**Check This out -**

**removeDuplicates**() function takes a string as an argument and then the string split function which is an inbuilt function splits it into an array of single **characters**. Then the **arr2** array which is empty at beginning, a **forEach** loop checks for every element in the **arr2** - if the **arr2** has the element it will not push the character in it, otherwise it will push. So the final array returned is with **unique elements.** Finally we join the array with the **join()** method to make it a **string**.

```
const removeDuplicates = (str) => {
const arr = str.split("");
const arr2 = [];

arr.forEach((el, i) => {
 if (!arr2.includes(el)) {
    arr2.push(el);
   }
 });
 return arr2.join("").replace(",", "").replace("", " ");
};

console.log(removeDuplicates( "Int32,Int32,Int32,Int32,Int32,Int32,Int32,Int32,Int32,Double,Double,Double"));
```

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion - I added an explanation.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Set()

```
const result = Array.from(new Set(x)).join('')
```

```js
var x = "Int32,Int32,Int32,Int32,Int32,Int32,Int32,Int32,Int32,Double,Double,Double"
const result = Array.from(new Set(x)).join('')

console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use the **replaceAll** function:

> let str = "/Courses/"
>
> let newStr = **str.replaceAll('/', '')**
>
> console.log(newStr) // result -> Courses

Answer (score -1):

```js
const str =  "Int32,Int32,Int32,Int32,Int32,Int32,Int32,Int32,Int32,Double,Double,Double";
const usingSpread = [...str]
const duplicatesRemove = [...new Set(usingSpread)]
const string = duplicatesRemove.join("")
console.log("After removing  duplicates: " + string)
```

**STEPS**

1. convert string to character array using spread operator
2. new Set will implicitly remove duplicate character
3. convert character array to string using join("") method

Comment: Your code splits the input string into individual characters instead of commas. It works for the OP's example, but will fail for inputs like `"Int32,Float,Double"`.