# How can I remove duplicate objects and sort?

Tags: javascript

I'm fetching pokemon names and images, and storing them like this.

```
   const pokemon = $(el)
      .find(".pokemon")
      .toArray()
      .map((el) => {
        const name = $(el).attr("title") || "";
        const image = $(el).find("img").attr("src") || "";
        return { name, image };
      });
```

I want a seperate variable that sorts by most reoccurring and then removes duplicates.
I tried using `byCount()` from this:

```
Array.prototype.byCount = function () {
  var itm,
    a = [],
    L = this.length,
    o = {};
  for (var i = 0; i < L; i++) {
    itm = this[i];
    if (!itm) continue;
    if (o[itm] == undefined) o[itm] = 1;
    else ++o[itm];
  }
  for (var p in o) a[a.length] = p;
  return a.sort(function (a, b) {
    return o[b] - o[a];
  });
};
```

and it worked if i fetch the name / image separately, but doesn't seem to work on an object.
the data is like

```
[name1, name1, name2, name3, name3, name4]
[img1, img1, img2, img3, img3, img4]
```

if i sort them individually using `byCount()` they don't always align so it might return:

```
[name1, name3, name2, name4]
[img3, img1, img2, img4]
```

since both img1 & img3 have the same occurance count.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Remove duplicate in a string - javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35609731/remove-duplicate-in-a-string-javascript)

Comment: Better duplicate [Get all unique values in a JavaScript array (remove duplicates)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1960473/get-all-unique-values-in-a-javascript-array-remove-duplicates)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
const repeatedItems = {}
arrayOfObjects.forEach((item) => {
  if (repeatedItems[item.name]) {
    repeatedItems[item.name] = { ...item, count: repeatedItems[item.name].count++ }
  } else {
    repeatedItems[item.name] = { ...item, count: 1 }
  }
})
const sortedArr = Object.values(repeatedItems).sort((a, b) => a.count - b.count).map((item) => ({ name: item.name, image: item.image }))
```

Comment: Thanks! this seems to work except it doesn't seem to sort by count https://jsfiddle.net/qdnashcb/

Comment: Edit: Got it working! Had to change `.count++` to `.count + 1` for some reason.

Answer (score -1):

To sort words with the prototype `sort`, use the `localeCompare` String prototype:

```
items.sort((a, b) => a.localeCompare(b))
```